# Почему при отведении курсора рамка пропадает моментально?

Tags: css, hover

FFF — вот код. Когда навожу на картинку все ок, ховер плавно появляется, когда отвожу в сторону моментально пропадает. Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это происходит из-за того, что при наведении Вы добавляете элементу с классом `.example3` рамку, которой до этого не было.

Переходы (transition) в CSS работают так, что должны быть точки начала и конца. А в Вашем случае получается, что рамки не было вообще, а потом добавилась.

Чтобы рамка резко не исчезала после отведения курсора, добавьте прозрачную рамку в обычном состоянии элемента. Например, `border: 0px solid transparent;`

Результат

```css
.example3 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 99%;
  height: 99%;
}

.example3 .example_text {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 25px 25px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.example_beauty {
  width: 99%;
  height: 99%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  /* transition: 0.6s */
}

.example3 {
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.example3:hover {
  border: 6px solid #e21837;
}

.example3 h6 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.example3 span {
  font-size: 12px;
}

</style>.btn:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <section style="display:inline-block">
    <div style="padding:20px;display:inline-block;">
      <div class="example3"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/400/536/354" class="example_beauty" />
        <div class="example_text">
          <h6>Я — заголовок</h6><span>А я — комментарий к этой прекрасной картинке. Я такой длинный, что занимаю несколько строчек.</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="padding:20px;display:inline-block;">
      <div class="example3"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/400/536/354" class="example_beauty" />
        <div class="example_text">
          <h6>Я — заголовок</h6><span>А я — комментарий к этой прекрасной картинке. Я такой длинный, что занимаю несколько строчек.</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="padding:20px;display:inline-block;">
      <div class="example3"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/400/536/354" class="example_beauty" />
        <div class="example_text">
          <h6>Я — заголовок</h6><span>А я — комментарий к этой прекрасной картинке. Я такой длинный, что занимаю несколько строчек.</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</center>

<h2>Fading Buttons - "Fade in Effect"</h2>

<button class="btn">Hover Over Me</button>
```

Comment: @ivan, если ответ помог, можете пометить его решением. Скриншоот галочки отметки: bit.ly/2Hss3VA

Answer (score 1):

Потому что `border`а изначально нет, а при ховере он добавляется, следовательно при обратном действие, он удаляется.

Вот несколько примеров как реализовать "плавное появление".

```css
.border-opacity {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 3px solid transparent; /* бордер есть изначально, но мы его не видем т.к. он прозрачный */
  transition: all .5s linear;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.border-opacity:hover {
  border-color: blue; /* далее при наведение на элемент мы меняем цвет бордера на синий */
}

.border-grow {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 0 solid blue; /* Тут бордер тоже есть, он синий, но мы его не видим из-за его нулевого размера */
  transition: all .5s linear;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.border-grow:hover {
  border-width: 3px; /* при наведение мы меняем его размер на три пикселя */
}
```

```html
<h2>border появляется</h2>

<div class="border-opacity"></div>

<h2>border "наростает"</h2>

<div class="border-grow"></div>
```